# Upgrading Linux (Fedora) with LUKS encrypted volume

Tags: fedora, upgrade, luks

I have FC18 on a `LUKS/dm-crypt` encrypted hard disk. I'd like to upgrade the system via a FC20 dvd.

I looked around a bit and it seems that upgrading the system via the installation procedure from the DVD would require some specific steps to ensure the correct recognition of the disk's contents.

The alternative would be, perhaps, to update yum repository and upgrade from there, but the first option seems "cleaner", and it has been so in my limited experience.

It's still not clear to me whether trying to make the DVD installer recognize the encrypted partition is an easy and reliable process.

Should I back up /home and perform a clean install?

Comment: Usually the clean approach is to let the system update itself and use DVD only for new installs. You should have a backup in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Fedora upgrade process has moved from the installer to [FedUp](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp), which you run *from the system to be upgraded*. (You can use the RPMs on the DVD media you have, although fetching them from the network is the recommended route.) Further instructions [on the FedUp page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp#How_Can_I_Upgrade_My_System_with_FedUp.3F).

Make sure you check a few F18→F20 gotchas on the [common bugs page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F20_bugs#fedup-07-fail) — make sure you have the latest FedUp, and either disable GPG checking (not recommended although okay if you verify the RPMs on your DVD first) or make sure you have the updated keys available.

This should handle encrypted volumes transparently with no fuss (except for an obscure case where you have upgraded from Grub 1 to Grub 2 by hand — if that *is* you, don't miss [this fix](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F20_bugs#Fedup:_upgrade_can.27t_start_without_rd.luks.uuid.2Frd.lvm.lv.2Frd.md.uuid_boot_args).)

*(Disclaimer: I work on Fedora, but not on the installer or FedUp specifically.)*